# Передача Object'а от одного Activity другому

Tags: android, сокет, activity, android-intent

Является ли метод `Intent.putExtra(String name, Serializable value)` адекватным способом передачи таких объектов, как `Socket`, от одного `Activity` другому?

- Пример: `Activity` подключения, передающий `Socket` `Activity` чата.

Comment: А почему не создавать сокет на уровне приложения? Или хранить сокет на уровне сервиса. Тогда сама проблема исчезает.

Comment: @KoVadim: просто мне как начинающему Android'исту показалось, что сама механика взаимодействия `Activity` в Android будто бы предостерегает нас от передачи чего бы то ни было "на уровне приложения".

Comment: изучите сервисы. Это как раз задача для них. В этом случае активити будут просто ображаться к сервису за запросом-ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, Android-разработка подразумевает вынесение того, что называется "*моделью*", или "*бизнес-логикой*" в `Service` (который здесь создаётся прямо в вызвавшем его `Thread`'e), а взаимодействие `Activity` между собой будто бы должно ограничиваться самыми тривиальными вещами, такими как обмен `requestCode` / `resultCode`.

Следовательно некоторые реализации `ConnectActivity` и `ChatActivity` должны взаимодействовать через посредничество некоторого `ChatClientService`.

Упрощённо такой `Service` можно представить как:

```
public class ChatClientService extends Service
{       
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        ChatClientService getService()
        { return ChatClientService.this; }
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    { return mBinder; }     

    private BluetoothSocket bSocket;

    // Метод инициализации подключения для ConnectActivity
    public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device)
    {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(getResources().getString(R.string.service_uuid));
        try
        {
            bSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            bSocket.connect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { /* Некоторая обработка исключения */ }
    }

    // Метод взаимодействия с подключением для ChatActivity
    public void sendMessage(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(str.getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { /* Некоторая обработка исключения */ }
    }
}
```

Тогда упрощённое взаимодействие с ним некоторого `Activity` может быть представлено как:

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity
{
    private ChatClientService chatClientService;

    private final ServiceConnection clientConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
        {
            // Получение ссылки на объект-сервис при успешном подключении
            chatClientService = ((ChatClientService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0)
        {
            // Неявное отключение ServiceConnection
            chatClientService = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat);

        // Привязка ChatClientService к ChatActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatClientService.class);
        bindService(intent, clientConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSendMessage);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input_message);
                // Пример взаимодействия с Service
                chatClientService.sendMessage(text.getText().toString());
                text.getText().clear();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Советую для использования сокетов применять сервис. Это будет более грамотное решение. Тогда любой Activity сможет просто обратиться к нему и всё.

Comment: Вы предлагаете создать `Service`, который будет служить глобальной точкой доступа к одному `Socket`'у? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous, да. Просто создается один сокет и все активити обращаются к нему через сервис.

Comment: вот только в комментарии есть плохой совет. Активити не должны знать о том, что есть сокет. Они должны знать о сервисе и о том, что он для них может выполнит отпределенные запросы. А как именно сервис будет передавать данные, упаковывать и распаковывать, активити знать не должны.